# Phonegap AJAX don't work on iOS and Android

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cors, phonegap

We are a little company using phonegap for our early build, but we are getting hit by a 404 ERROR / CORS.

I'm using .Net Framework for my API - And CORS is fully setup.

So basicly, when i launch on my app on my desktop through the phonegap development tool it works, but if i disable my "CORS" extensions it wont.

But when i build my app for IOS and Android, the installation process etc is working wonders, but my problem is i can't get my app to gain access to the API - It doesn't hit the AJAX call.

I don't think CORS is necessary on phones, if i'm correct.

NOTE: My API is currently running on HTTP and not HTTPS.

CSP: ( Allowing everything but still doesn't work )

"meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *" /"

CONFIG.XML:  ( I Removed icon, name and app descriptions.)

```
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />

</platform>
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

AJAX CALL:

```
function Login() {
    var Email = $("#pass").val();
    var Password = $("#bruger").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://myapiserver.com/' + Email + '/' + Password,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.ID > 0 && data.Username !== null) {
                console.log("", data.Id);
                console.log("", data.Username);
                window.localStorage.setItem("user", data.Id);
                window.localStorage.setItem("namefield", data.Username);
                window.location.assign("main.html");

            } else {
                $("#msg").html("<span style=\"color: black;\" class=\"alert\">Brugeren blev ikke fundet!</span>"); 
            }
        }
    });

        if (window.localStorage.getItem("user")!== null) {
            window.location.assign("main.html");
        }

}
```

I have been reading something about WebView causing the error, but since IOS is also failing i don't think this is the cause and it should also be solved in the latest patches of WebView.

I might need to update some SDK's or something, but since i use the Phonegap tool create the app i have no idea how to do that. (might need some help)

The whole app is working in browsers and is "DONE" when it works on IOS and Andoid - but i really need to figure this out as fast as possible as we have investor meetings in a week.

I really hope somebody knows what's going on here - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will absolutely have to implement HTTPS on myapiserver.com, even for devlepment. iPhone via the PhoneGap API especially will block requests to outside URLs when they don't go over HTTPS. I built a PhoneGap app that hit this exact issue. You can try adding it to allowed URLs, but Apple will just block it when it doesn't use HTTPS with no real error reason why. You will need to add an SSL to both your dev and prod server URLS for that web service. I'm assuming Android has followed suite.

Comment: I already tried adding SSL and running it through HTTPS, its the same result.

There's so many having this problem atm, and none seem to get it solved from what i can see and hear from other people.